# Loopback connection always refused in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I've just spent two days on this. This is run in the game engine Unity3D, but that shouldn't make a difference. These two lines ALWAYS fail:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 15219));
```

The error I get is:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remote_end_point) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at StreamIn.Connect (System.String server, System.String message) [0x00011] in C:\XXX\StreamIn.cs:41 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
StreamIn:uPrint(String) (at Assets/StreamIn.cs:27)
StreamIn:Connect(String, String) (at Assets/StreamIn.cs:77)
StreamIn:Start() (at Assets/StreamIn.cs:18)
```

I've tried everything, including changing my firewall settings and disabling the firewall.

I get the same error with a dummy IP address.

If I try port `80` instead of `15219`, the Unity editor freezes. (I do have a web server running.)

Am I missing something obvious? Or not obvious?

Comment: What is your client connecting to?

Comment: In this example, itself, for test purposes. Eventually, it will connect to a Java app on the same machine.

Comment: Have you tried IPAddress.Loopback instead of IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")?

Comment: I think this is hitting me with the painful blow of obviousness. I need a separate server process running at the same time, don't I?

Comment: I'll try IPAddress.Loopback right now. Just tried it. Same result.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a communication service of some kind (ex: wcf) running for your client to be able to connect to

Comment: @eje211 You *do* have a server listening on port 15219, right?  For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

Comment: I started a Python server for test purposes and now it works.

Comment: @eje211, please do not obfuscate your original question, otherwise people will not know what question was answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find it useful to sanity check these things with a different network tool outside of my .NET code. I think [hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) is great for this as you can easily open up a tcp server for you app to connect to, and/or test a connection from a client perspective.